Generic Min() for Integer Types (including Boolean)
This is a follow-up to Generic Max() for Integer Types (including Boolean) and An Attempt at Creating Generic Min()/Max() for Fundamental Types.
What's new:

MIN(), that was abandoned despondent, has been revived. MAX() and its tests were done with in the last post, this post implements a generic MIN() with MAX().
Again, floating point types haven't been entertained, and types narrower than int haven't been checked for (they are implicitly promoted to int by adding 0).

Code:
#ifndef MIN_H
#define MIN_H 1

#include <limits.h>

#include "max.h"

/* Current versions of gcc and clang support -std=c2x which sets 
 * __STDC_VERSION__ to this placeholder value. GCC 14.1 does not set
 * __STDC_VERSION__ to 202311L with the std=c23 flag, but Clang 18.1 does. */
#define C23_PLACEHOLDER 202000L
    
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION >= C23_PLACEHOLDER
    /* gnu::const is stricter than unsequenced, but it doesn't matter here. */
    #define ATTRIB_CONST            [[unsequenced]]
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_CONST            __attribute__((const))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_CONST            /**/
#endif

#if defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE    __attribute__((always_inline))
#else
    #define ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE    /**/
#endif

#define gen_basic_min(return_type, param_type1, param_type2, suffix)   \
    ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline return_type min_##suffix(param_type1 a, param_type2 b) \
    { return a < b ? (return_type) a : (return_type) b; }

#define gen_nonbasic_min(return_type, param_type1, param_type2, cast_type, suffix) \
    ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline return_type min_##suffix(param_type1 a, param_type2 b) \
    { return max_##suffix(a, b) == a ? b : (cast_type) a; }

gen_basic_min(int, int, int, i_i)
gen_basic_min(long, int, long, i_li)
gen_basic_min(long long, int, long long, i_lli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline int min_i_ui(int a, unsigned b)
{
    return max_i_ui(a, b) == b ? a : (int) b;
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline int min_i_uli(int a, unsigned long b)
{
    return max_i_uli(a, b) == b ? a : (int) b;
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline int min_i_ulli(int a, unsigned long long b)
{
    return max_i_ulli(a, b) == b ? a : (int) b;
}

#define MIN_I(a, b)     _Generic((b),                                   \
                            int:                    min_i_i,            \
                            unsigned int:           min_i_ui,           \
                            long int:               min_i_li,           \
                            unsigned long int:      min_i_uli,          \
                            long long int:          min_i_lli,          \
                            unsigned long long int: min_i_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_min(unsigned, unsigned, unsigned, ui_ui)
gen_basic_min(unsigned, unsigned, unsigned long, ui_uli)
gen_basic_min(unsigned, unsigned, unsigned long long, ui_ulli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline int min_ui_i(unsigned a, int b)
{
    return min_i_ui(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long min_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
{
    #if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
    return max_ui_li(a, b) == b ? (long) a : b;
    #else
    return max_ui_li(a, b) == a ? b : (long) a;
    #endif
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long min_ui_lli(unsigned a, long long b)
{
    #if LLONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
    return max_ui_lli(a, b) == b ? (long long) a : b;
    #else
    return max_ui_lli(a, b) == a ? b : (long long) a;
    #endif
}

#define MIN_UI(a, b)     _Generic((b),                                  \
                            int:                    min_ui_i,           \
                            unsigned int:           min_ui_ui,          \
                            long int:               min_ui_li,          \
                            unsigned long int:      min_ui_uli,         \
                            long long int:          min_ui_lli,         \
                            unsigned long long int: min_ui_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_min(long, long, int, li_i)
gen_basic_min(long, long, long, li_li)
gen_basic_min(long long, long, long long, li_lli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long min_li_ui(long a, unsigned b)
{
    return min_ui_li(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long min_li_uli(long a, unsigned long b)
{
    return max_li_uli(a, b) == b ? a : (long) b;
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long min_li_ulli(long a, unsigned long long b)
{
    return max_li_ulli(a, b) == b ? a : (long) b;
}

#define MIN_LI(a, b)    _Generic((b),                                   \
                            int:                    min_li_i,           \
                            unsigned int:           min_li_ui,          \
                            long int:               min_li_li,          \
                            unsigned long int:      min_li_uli,         \
                            long long int:          min_li_lli,         \
                            unsigned long long int: min_li_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_min(unsigned, unsigned long, unsigned, uli_ui)
gen_basic_min(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, uli_uli)
gen_basic_min(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long long, uli_ulli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline int min_uli_i(unsigned long a, int b)
{
    return min_i_uli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long min_uli_li(unsigned long a, long b)
{
    return min_li_uli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long min_uli_lli(unsigned long a, long long b)
{
    #if LLONG_MAX >= ULONG_MAX
    return max_uli_lli(a, b) == b ? (long long) a : b;
    #else
    return max_uli_lli(a, b) == a ? b : (long long) a;
    #endif
}

#define MIN_ULI(a, b)   _Generic((b),                                   \
                            int:                    min_uli_i,          \
                            unsigned int:           min_uli_ui,         \
                            long int:               min_uli_li,         \
                            unsigned long int:      min_uli_uli,        \
                            long long int:          min_uli_lli,        \
                            unsigned long long int: min_uli_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_min(long long, long long, int, lli_i)
gen_basic_min(long long, long long, long, lli_li)
gen_basic_min(long long, long long, long long, lli_lli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long min_lli_ui(long long a, unsigned b)
{
    return min_ui_lli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long min_lli_uli(long long a, unsigned long b)
{
    return min_uli_lli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long min_lli_ulli(long long a, unsigned long long b)
{
    return max_lli_ulli(a, b) == b ? a : (long long) b;
}

#define MIN_LLI(a, b)   _Generic((b),                                   \
                            int:                    min_lli_i,          \
                            unsigned int:           min_lli_ui,         \
                            long int:               min_lli_li,         \
                            unsigned long int:      min_lli_uli,        \
                            long long int:          min_lli_lli,        \
                            unsigned long long int: min_lli_ulli)((a), (b))

gen_basic_min(unsigned, unsigned long long, unsigned, ulli_ui)
gen_basic_min(unsigned long, unsigned long long, unsigned long, ulli_uli)
gen_basic_min(unsigned long long, unsigned long long, unsigned long long, ulli_ulli)

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline int min_ulli_i(unsigned long long a, int b)
{
    return min_i_ulli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long min_ulli_li(unsigned long long a, long b)
{
    return min_li_ulli(b, a);
}

ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long min_ulli_lli(unsigned long long a, long long b)
{
    return min_lli_ulli(b, a);
}

#define MIN_ULLI(a, b)  _Generic((b),                                   \
                            int:                    min_ulli_i,         \
                            unsigned int:           min_ulli_ui,        \
                            long int:               min_ulli_li,        \
                            unsigned long int:      min_ulli_uli,       \
                            long long int:          min_ulli_lli,       \
                            unsigned long long int: min_ulli_ulli)((a), (b))

#define MIN(a, b)       _Generic((a) + 0,                                       \
                            int:                    MIN_I((a) + 0, (b) + 0),    \
                            unsigned int:           MIN_UI((a) + 0, (b) + 0),   \
                            long int:               MIN_LI((a) + 0, (b) + 0),   \
                            unsigned long int:      MIN_ULI((a) + 0, (b) + 0),  \
                            long long int:          MIN_LLI((a) + 0, (b) + 0),  \
                            unsigned long long int: MIN_ULLI((a) + 0, (b) + 0))

#undef ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE
#undef ATTRIB_CONST
#undef C23_PLACEHOLDER

#endif  /* MIN_H */

And here are some tests:
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

#include "min.h"

/* Current versions of gcc and clang support -std=c2x which sets 
 * __STDC_VERSION__ to this placeholder value. GCC 14.1 does not set
 * __STDC_VERSION__ to 202311L with the std=c23 flag, but Clang 18.1 does. */
#define C23_PLACEHOLDER 202000L
    
#if defined(__STDC_VERSION__) && __STDC_VERSION >= C23_PLACEHOLDER
    #define NORETURN    [[noreturn]]
#elif defined(_MSC_VER)
    #define NORETURN    __declspec(noreturn)
#elif defined(__GNUC__) || defined(__clang__) || defined(__INTEL_LLVM_COMPILER)
    #define NORETURN    __attribute__((noreturn))
#else
    #define NORETURN    _Noreturn
#endif

NORETURN static void cassert(const char cond[static 1], 
                             const char file[static 1],
                             size_t line)
{
    fflush(stdout);
    fprintf(stderr, "Assertion failed: '%s' at %s, line %zu.\n", cond, file, line);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

#define test(cond) do { \
    if (!(cond)) { cassert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__); } } while (false)

/* Get the name of a type */
#define ctypename(x) _Generic((x),                                  \
                _Bool: "_Bool",                                     \
                unsigned char: "unsigned char",                     \
                char: "char",                                       \
                signed char: "signed char",                         \
                short: "short",                                     \
                unsigned short: "unsigned short",                   \
                int: "int",                                         \
                unsigned: "unsigned",                               \
                long: "long",                                       \
                unsigned long: "unsigned long",                     \
                long long: "long long",                             \
                unsigned long long: "unsigned long long",           \
                default: "other")

static const int imax = INT_MAX;
static const unsigned umax = UINT_MAX;
static const long lmax = LONG_MAX;
static const unsigned long ulmax = ULONG_MAX;
static const long long llmax = LLONG_MAX;
static const unsigned long long ullmax = ULLONG_MAX;

static const long lmin = LONG_MIN;
static const int imin = INT_MIN;
static const long long llmin = LLONG_MIN;

static void test_min_int(void) 
{
    test(MIN(3, 5) == 3 && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3, 5)), "int") == 0);
    test(MIN(5, 3) == 3 && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5, 3)), "int") == 0);
    test(MIN(imax, imin) == imin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(imax, imin)), "int") == 0);
    test(MIN(imin, imax) == imin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(imin, imax)), "int") == 0);
    test(MIN(0, imax) == 0 && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0, imax)), "int") == 0);
    test(MIN(0, imin) == imin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0, imin)), "int") == 0);
}

static void test_min_unsigned_int(void) 
{
    test(MIN(3U, 5U) == 3U && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3U, 5U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MIN(5U, 3U) == 3U && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5U, 3U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MIN(umax, 0U) == 0U && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(umax, 0U)), "unsigned") == 0);
}

static void test_min_long(void) 
{
    test(MIN(3L, 5L) == 3L && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3L, 5L)), "long") == 0);
    test(MIN(5L, 3L) == 3L && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5L, 3L)), "long") == 0);
    test(MIN(lmax, lmin) == lmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(lmax, lmin)), "long") == 0);
    test(MIN(lmin, lmax) == lmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(lmin, lmax)), "long") == 0);
    test(MIN(0L, lmax) == 0L && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0L, lmax)), "long") == 0);
    test(MIN(0L, lmin) == lmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0L, lmin)), "long") == 0);
}

static void test_min_unsigned_long(void) 
{
    test(MIN(3UL, 5UL) == 3UL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3UL, 5UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MIN(5UL, 3UL) == 3UL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5UL, 3UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MIN(ulmax, 0UL) == 0UL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(ulmax, 0UL)), "unsigned long") == 0);
    test(MIN(0UL, ulmax) == 0UL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0UL, ulmax)), "unsigned long") == 0);
}

static void test_min_long_long(void) 
{
    test(MIN(3LL, 5LL) == 3LL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3LL, 5LL)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(5LL, 3LL) == 3LL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5LL, 3LL)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(llmax, llmin) == llmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(llmax, llmin)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(llmin, llmax) == llmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(llmin, llmax)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(0LL, llmax) == 0LL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0LL, llmax)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(0LL, llmin) == llmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0LL, llmin)), "long long") == 0);
}

static void test_min_unsigned_long_long(void) 
{
    test(MIN(3ULL, 5ULL) == 3ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3ULL, 5ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(5ULL, 3ULL) == 3ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5ULL, 3ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(ullmax, 0ULL) == 0ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(ullmax, 0ULL)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(0ULL, ullmax) == 0ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(0ULL, ullmax)), "unsigned long long") == 0);
}

static void test_min_mixed(void) 
{
    test(MIN(3, 5U) == 3 && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3, 5U)), "int") == 0);
    test(MIN(5U, 3) == 3 && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5U, 3)), "int") == 0);

    test(MIN(3L, 5) == 3L && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3L, 5)), "long") == 0);
    test(MIN(5, 3L) == 3L && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5, 3L)), "long") == 0);

    test(MIN(3LL, 5) == 3LL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3LL, 5)), "long long") == 0);
    test(MIN(5, 3LL) == 3LL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5, 3LL)), "long long") == 0);

    test(MIN(3ULL, 5) == 3ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3ULL, 5)), "int") == 0);
    test(MIN(5, 3ULL) == 3ULL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5, 3ULL)), "int") == 0);

    test(MIN(3UL, 5U) == 3UL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(3UL, 5U)), "unsigned") == 0);
    test(MIN(5U, 3UL) == 3UL && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(5U, 3UL)), "unsigned") == 0);
}

int main(void) 
{
    test_min_int();
    test_min_unsigned_int();
    test_min_long();
    test_min_unsigned_long();
    test_min_long_long();
    test_min_unsigned_long_long();
    test_min_mixed();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

The code compiles cleanly under Clang 18.1 with a strict set of warnings (-Wconversion included), and these tests all pass.
Both of these files are present here: utils.
Review Request:
Bugs, wrong comparisons, redundant comparisons, portability. Any missing types?

Edit: The code was compiled with Clang 18.1 on a Linux Mint 21.2 x86_64 virtual machine with the following compiler flags:
clang-18 -std=c2x -g3 -ggdb -no-pie -Wall -Wextra -Warray-bounds -Wconversion -Wformat-signedness -Wmissing-braces -Wno-parentheses -Wpedantic -Wstrict-prototypes -Wwrite-strings -Winline -s -fno-builtin -fno-common -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fsanitize=float-cast-overflow -fsanitize=address -fsanitize=undefined -fsanitize=leak    max_test.c   -o max_test

It emitted no warnings, except that Wformat-signedness is an unknown warning option.

"The code compiles cleanly under Clang 18.1 with a strict set of warnings (-Wconversion included)" ==> The same can not be said for GCC 13.1, which emits a myriad of warnings, absolutely bamboozling behavior. (The warnings make no sense to me, and I haven't added them here).

With your header in min.h, the test code in test-min.c, and max.h — which has to be collected from Generic max() function for integer types (including boolean) — many versions of GCC generate warnings from your code (assuming a 64-bit compilation).

GCC 14.1.0 (with -std=c23)
GCC 13.2.0 (with -std=c2x)
GCC 12.2.0 (with -std=c2x)
GCC 11.2.0 (with -std=c2x)
I'm testing on an antique Linux box (Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 7.4 (Maipo)), and the compilations are 64-bit by default.  I built all the versions of GCC.

The errors from GCC 14.1.0 are:
$ gcc -std=c23 -Wall -Werror -Wextra -c test-min.c
In file included from min.h:6,
                 from test-min.c:7:
max.h: In function ‘max_ui_li’:
max.h:67:11: error: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
   67 |     if (a <= LONG_MAX) {
      |           ^~
max.h: In function ‘max_ui_lli’:
max.h:79:11: error: comparison is always true due to limited range of data type [-Werror=type-limits]
   79 |     if (a <= LLONG_MAX) {
      |           ^~
max.h: In function ‘max_uli_lli’:
max.h:146:28: error: operand of ‘?:’ changes signedness from ‘long long int’ to ‘long unsigned int’ due to unsignedness of other operand [-Werror=sign-compare]
  146 |         return b < 0 ? a : ((long long) a > b ? (long long) a : b);
      |                            ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$

I get the same warnings/errors from the test code in the "Generic max()" question.
It's irksome that the errors are from code not supplied with this question — there's a chance that you've made changes to that code to fix the errors, but how are the poor, gullible muggins who answer this question supposed to guess that?
The relevant code in max.h is (line numbers included):
 61 #if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
 62 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
 63 #else
 64 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
 65 #endif
 66 {
 67     if (a <= LONG_MAX) {
 68         return b < 0 ? a : ((long) a > b ? (long)a : b);
 69     }
 70     return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned) b ? a : (unsigned) b);
 71 }

The complaint for line 67 is "comparison is always true due to limited range of data type", which is accurate since unsigned is a 32-bit type and long is a 64-bit type.  A similar analysis applies to line 79.
The difficulty is working out how to fix it.  The C preprocessor cannot test sizeof(), so testing UINT_MAX and LONG_MAX (or LLONG_MAX) will do the job.
For the max_ui_li() function, this can become:
 61 #if LONG_MAX >= UINT_MAX
 62 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
 63 #else
 64 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned max_ui_li(unsigned a, long b)
 65 #endif
 66 {
 67 #if LLONG_MAX < UINT_MAX
 68     if (a <= LONG_MAX) {
 69         return b < 0 ? a : ((long) a > b ? (long)a : b);
 70     }
 71     return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned) b ? a : (unsigned) b);
 72 #else
 73     return b < 0 ? a : ((long) a > b ? (long)a : b);
 74 #endif
 75 }

and similarly for max_ui_lli().
With those two changes in place, the other complaint moves to line 154:
147 #if LLONG_MAX >= ULONG_MAX
148 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long max_uli_lli(unsigned long a, long long b)
149 #else
150 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_uli_lli(unsigned long a, long long b)
151 #endif
152 {
153     if (a <= LLONG_MAX) {
154         return b < 0 ? a : ((long long) a > b ? (long long) a : b);
155     }
156     return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned long) b ? a : (unsigned long) b);
157 }

Since a is unsigned long and b is long long, but sizeof(unsigned long) == sizeof(long long), the complaint is, again, correct.  The fix is similar — another conditional test.
147 #if LLONG_MAX >= ULONG_MAX
148 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline long long max_uli_lli(unsigned long a, long long b)
149 #else
150 ATTRIB_ALWAYS_INLINE ATTRIB_CONST static inline unsigned long max_uli_lli(unsigned long a, long long b)
151 #endif
152 {
153 #if ULLONG_MAX > ULONG_MAX
154     if (a <= LLONG_MAX) {
155         return b < 0 ? a : ((long long) a > b ? (long long) a : b);
156     }
157     return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned long) b ? a : (unsigned long) b);
158 #else
159     if (a <= LLONG_MAX) {
160         return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned long) b ? a : (unsigned long) b);
161     }
162     return b < 0 ? a : (a > (unsigned long) b ? a : (unsigned long) b);
163 #endif
164 }

With these changes, both test-min.c and test-max.c (the test code from the "Generic max()" question) compile without complaints from GCC 14.1.0 and run without producing any output, which I interpret as "success".
However, compiling with GCC 13.2.0 generates a lot of warnings from test-min.c complaining about uses of MIN defined in min.h.  The first couple of warnings are:
$ /usr/gcc/v13.2.0/bin/gcc -o test-min -std=c2x -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror test-min.c
test-min.c: In function ‘test_min_long’:
min.h:211:63: error: overflow in conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int’ changes value from ‘9223372036854775807’ to ‘-1’ [-Werror=overflow]
  211 |                             int:                    MIN_I((a) + 0, (b) + 0),    \
      |                                                               ^
test-min.c:34:11: note: in definition of macro ‘test’
   34 |     if (!(cond)) { cassert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__); } } while (false)
      |           ^~~~
min.h:211:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘MIN_I’
  211 |                             int:                    MIN_I((a) + 0, (b) + 0),    \
      |                                                     ^~~~~
test-min.c:84:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘MIN’
   84 |     test(MIN(lmax, lmin) == lmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(lmax, lmin)), "long") == 0);
      |          ^~~
min.h:212:64: error: unsigned conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘unsigned int’ changes value from ‘9223372036854775807’ to 4294967295’ [-Werror=overflow]
  212 |                             unsigned int:           MIN_UI((a) + 0, (b) + 0),   \
      |                                                                ^
test-min.c:34:11: note: in definition of macro ‘test’
   34 |     if (!(cond)) { cassert(#cond, __FILE__, __LINE__); } } while (false)
      |           ^~~~
min.h:212:53: note: in expansion of macro ‘MIN_UI’
  212 |                             unsigned int:           MIN_UI((a) + 0, (b) + 0),   \
      |                                                     ^~~~~~
test-min.c:84:10: note: in expansion of macro ‘MIN’
   84 |     test(MIN(lmax, lmin) == lmin && strcmp(ctypename(MIN(lmax, lmin)), "long") == 0);
      |          ^~~
…
cc1: all warnings being treated as errors
$

There are 12 error: lines, each with 3 note: lines to expand on the error.  Understanding all those is going to take time.

I thought GCC might be hallucinating, as Clang wasn't complaining. Looks like I am in a deep mess. Thank you for your time. The code for MAX() is as it was, apologies if irked thee. :)

Would testing with Clang version 15.0.0 (clang-1500.3.9.4) on macOS help?  AFAICT, that's pretty much the latest version — at least until WWDC next week.  I'll have to copy the code from the Linux box (which doesn't have Clang installed), but that's not a major pain (unlike dealing with all the contortions in "simple" code to calculate minimum/maximum values).

You should probably document the compiler flags you're using in the question.  I suspect you are not using -Weverything -Werror (which is sane, because -Weverything is too harsh; you have to set various -Wno-… options too to get rid of blatantly irrelevant issues (-Wno-poison-system-directories, for example).

I have added the compiler flags, as well as the Clang version in my question.

I added most of those flags and GCC 14.1.0 was still happy with the code.  I used: gcc -o test-min -O3 -std=c23 -Wall  -Wextra  -Warray-bounds  -Wconversion  -Wformat-signedness  -Wmissing-braces  -Wno-parentheses  -Wpedantic  -Wstrict-prototypes  -Wwrite-strings  -Winline -fno-builtin  -fno-common  -fno-omit-frame-pointer  -fsanitize=float-cast-overflow  -fsanitize=address  -fsanitize=undefined  -fsanitize=leak test-min.c

For max_test.c, GCC 13.1 with the flags you mentioned emitted around 100 or so warnings, with 3 notes for each.... Though somewhat less for min_test.c. I will look at them and fix them all. Thank you.

For max_test.c, GCC 13.1 with the flags you mentioned emitted around 100 or so warnings, with 3 notes for each.... Though somewhat less for min_test.c.  I removed -Wconversion and they all dissapeared. I will look at them and fix them all. Thank you.

With GCC 13.2.0 I got 18 errors from attempting to compile what I called test-max.c, compared with 12 from attempting to compile test-min.c.  Things change.  I also got 36 "note" lines from each compilation, so 2 per error on average for test-max.c vs 3 per error for test-min.c.  And I agree that most of the options are not going to detect problems with the code, and -Wconversion is the primary … is 'culprit' the right word?

The only meaningful warnings I find are the ones you got from GCC 14.1. The ones from GCC 13.1/13.2 do not make any sense to me. To analyze the first warnings you got from GCC 13.2, "conversion from ‘long int’ to ‘int’" make no sense because the case _Generic picked was int, which means that the type of a was an int. Adding 0 to an int can not make it a long int, nor would an int overflow if 0 is added to it. Perhaps Lundin is right to say that -Wconversion has a lot of false positives and is not very useful.

That's a distinct possibility — and it would appear that GCC 14.1.0 has greatly improved over GCC 13.2.0 (13.1.0).  I've not yet built GCC 13.3.0 (released on 2024-05-21), so I don't know whether the improvements are present there, yet.
